# Does jQuery need plugin for making few CSS3 options equal to CSS3?

Tags: jquery, css

To summarize - if I change the css of an element with jQuery to include a transform, how can I make it so that the original style is still kept intact on this element? ~Thank you @Shikkediel for correction.

Comment: Not sure what you are asking, but there is no way to enhance CSS engine that is present in the browser. jQuery can give you new ways to *set* the CSS, but the CSS rules written in a style sheet can do no more nor less than CSS rules set by jQuery.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you would need to be aware of the fact that when you dynamically set style to a certain property that is already set (like this transform), then the old style will be cleared. If you want to keep them both, include the original in the jQuery manipulation as well.

```
#element {
-webkit-transform: skew(-25deg);
transform: skew(-25deg);
}
```

```
var transforms = 'skew(-25deg) rotate(45deg)';
$('#element').css({'-webkit-transform': transforms, 'transform': transforms});
```

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/PwvqMm

Comment: Thats what i needed :)! Thanks for understanding for my bad england (pun intended)

Comment: Cheers, I guess it wasn't that clear a question to everyone but I got the gist of it.